Is there a way to add an if statement to a message pop-up in R?
I'm working on some code to clean a dataset and before exporting I need to check if there are any NA values which is done using
navalues <- sum(is.na(data$postcode))

I would like to add a pop-up message if the value is greater than 0. I found the tcltk package and the following code which shows a text box
require(tcltk)
msgBox <- tkmessageBox(title = "NA Values Detected",
                       message = "There are NA values present in this dataset. Postcodes must be added before running analysis.", icon = "info", type = "ok")

My question is, can I add an if statement to the tcltk messageBox function to trigger the pop-up only when there are NA values in the dataset?
Or would I be better off just creating a custom warning to stop the code from running when this is the case?

Did you tried to put your call to msgBox inside a if statement if (navalues > 0) { msgBox <- tkmessageBox (...); stop()}?

@MAurélio I finally got it working using this code. Thank you very much!
